# Is there a simple way to manually change font with font size in XeTeX?

Tags: fonts, xetex, fontsize, fontspec

Many typfaces come with different fonts for different font sizes. For example [Surveyor Pro](http://www.typography.com/fonts/surveyor/styles/) has a Book style for main text and a Display style for headings (or in general, large text). Another example is the open source project [XITS](https://github.com/khaledhosny/xits-math) which if scaled down to smaller text needs kerning pair adjustments (which result in a different font).

In these cases one could redefine the \Huge or \footnotesize environment and use the fontspec package to associate different fonts with those commands. This however is a rather hacky way and could lead to more problems. So hence my question.

*Is there a simple way to **manually** change font with font size in XeTeX?*

EDIT: I should point out that fontspec recognises optical scaling and would therefore automatically pick a different font for a different size if available. There are a lot of SizeFeatures too (as described in the fontspec manual) such as changing colour, kerning values et cetera. Is it possible though to change font? For example:

```
\setmainfont{Typeface}[SizeFeatures = {{Size =   -8, <Font_A>},
                                       {Size = 8-12, <Font_B>},
                                       {Size = 12- , <Font_C>}}]
```

For the argument's sake Font_A should be Garamond and Font_B should be Times New Roman and Font_C can be Surveyor Pro Display.

Comment: It's an interesting question. I have not explore yet XeTeX so deep for reply properly your question, but below my own experience with different fonts in DPAs, those professional fonts need a better control, the most of times manually. I think that in XeTeX the ease won't be greater, at least not by default.

Comment: Are we talking optical sizes here or something else? The part about 'display text' suggests you are thinking of what would normally be regarded as different fonts, not simply different optical design sizes.

Comment: @ChrisS I can see that this is done automatically with CM, but for other systems you might have to manually specify *for which size range which font to use*. So I wouldn't say it's a duplicate.

Comment: @JosephWright I would argue that in many cases optical sizes are directly linked to (and therefore mean)  different fonts. (Not strictly of course. I'm referring to size regimes, e.g. Size 9 pt to 12 pt *Book*, 18 pt to 32 pt *Display*)

Comment: I suspect here the answer is 'no': the `fontspec` mechanism is about optical sizes of what the designer regards as the same font rather than actually changing font. (Semantically, the font size commands are only supposed to change the size, so that's not an unreasonable position.)

Comment: In case of the CM example, which was brought up here, there are actually 3 fonts: CM10, CM12 and CM17 all of which are parts of the typeface or (as I understand) font family. The difference to my question is that CM10, CM12 and CM17 are picked automatically by the XeTeX engine because they are represented as different optical scaling groups; yet many typefaces won't have these scaling features (They still provide a display font though). So a bit more control in this respect would be a good idea wouldn't it?

Comment: @JosephWright The important point being that for most fonts, optical sizes come in separate font files — so changing optical sizes is the same as changing fonts.

Comment: @WillRobertson Yes, different files but the designer intends them to be used 'together' (separate files for technical not design reasons): that's not the same as two similar fonts which the designer described independently. (I assume no special treatment is needed for multiple master font files, rare as they are.)

Comment: @JosephWright — Multiple master fonts tend to get used as "instances"; you load the font with some particular parameters set for the shape you want. But I haven't tested MM fonts for years; they're not supported with the standard drivers AFAIK.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, so I found the answer to my own question. It turns out I was pretty close:

```
\setmainfont[SizeFeatures = {{Size =   -8, Font = <Font_A>},
                             {Size = 8-12, Font = <Font_B>},
                             {Size = 12- , Font = <Font_C>}}]{<Typeface>}
```

produces exactly what I wanted.

Comment: Isn't this the same as the example in your question? Not sure where the misunderstanding was originally.

Comment: @WillRobertson Almost, it's missing the `,Font = ' bit. I should have seen that earlier I guess. Still, this might be helpful for others.

Comment: — Ah, I must be blind! Thanks. (BTW, probably best to be consistent with where the optional argument to `\setmainfont` goes.)